# Capture dll logs to log it via slf4j/logback

Tags: java, c++, dll, slf4j, logback

I have a question about logback configuration.
We have currently an application written in Java and using slf4j/logback as logging framework.
This application use a C++ dll and access it via JNA (Java Native Access).
This dll send its error logs on the stderr stream.

My question here is, how can I capture all the stuff logged by the dll and log it via logback in a classic way ?

Thank you,

Seb

Comment: What's your definition of "classic way"?

Comment: As in the java code. Just intercept the c++ logs and put it in my java log files via something like LOGGER.info(someC++Message).

Comment: You can try using `System.setOut()` or `System.setErr()`